# How to create a folder using .tt template?

Tags: c#, .net, t4

I'm trying to build a template that will create a series of files in different folders but I haven't found any samples.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `RenderToFile` from [t4Toolbox](https://github.com/olegsych/T4Toolbox) to do this.

Snippet from documentation example as of 2016.10.12:

> - Create a Visual Studio solution with two C# Class Library projects   ClassLibrary1.csproj and ClassLibrary2.csproj.
> - Add a new code generation file called CodeGenerator.tt to the first class library project.
> - Modify contents of the new file to look like so

```
<#@ template language="C#" hostspecific="True" debug="True" #>
<#@ output extension="txt" #>
<#@ include file="T4Toolbox.tt" #>
<#
    SampleTemplate template = new SampleTemplate();
    template.Output.File = @"SubFolder\SampleOutput.txt";
    template.Output.Project = @"..\ClassLibrary2\ClassLibrary2.csproj";
    template.Render();
#>
<#+
    public class SampleTemplate : Template
    {
        public override string TransformText()
        {
            this.WriteLine("Hello, World!");
            return this.GenerationEnvironment.ToString();
        }
    }
#>
```

[Original Documentation](http://www.olegsych.com/2009/03/t4-toolbox-generating-files-in-different-folders-and-projects/)

[Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20160425021329/http://www.olegsych.com/2009/03/t4-toolbox-generating-files-in-different-folders-and-projects/)

Comment: [Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @ErikPhilips Exactly! Page appears to be dead (404). Luckily Wayback Machine exists.

Answer (score 0):

the code create a folder in disk d: and **system.io** required run vs as administrator.

```
    <#@ template debug="true" hostspecific="false" language="C#" #>
    <#@ assembly name="System.Core" #>
    <#@ import namespace="System.Linq" #>
    <#@ import namespace="System.Text" #>
    <#@ import namespace="System.IO" #>
    <#@ import namespace="System.Collections.Generic" #>
    <#@ output extension=".txt" #>

    <# 
            var dir = "d://ddd";
            if (Directory.Exists(dir))
            {
                Directory.Delete(dir);
            }
            Directory.CreateDirectory(dir);
    #>
```

That 's OK!